# Excel VBA run macro across dynamic range of sheets

Tags: vba, excel

As an extension from the last question I asked, I'm trying to run a macro across all worksheets, which you guys successfully helped me to do.
I've been told that the worksheet names can't be hardcoded, so I'm going to have to modify my current solution.

```
Sub RemoveCarriageReturns()
Dim MyRange As Range
Dim NameList() As Variant
NameList = Array("OTCUEXTR", "OTFBCUDS", "OTFBCUEL")
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

For i = 0 To 2
    With Worksheets(NameList(i))
        For Each MyRange In .UsedRange
            If 0 < InStr(MyRange, Chr(10)) Then
                MyRange = Replace(MyRange, Chr(10), "")
            End If
        Next MyRange
    End With
Next i

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
End Sub
```

I've tried to populate the array with a For loop that gathers names of each worksheet however I feel after 2 days blankly staring at this,  my limited VBA knowledge has run out and I'm stuck, I would really appreciate some pointers on how to get this macro to work across an range of sheets that can change in quantity and names.

Happy to provide any more information you need in a comment

Comment: Do you mean all worksheets in the workbook, or a selection?

Comment: @sjr All of the worksheets.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it like this (or could use the index along the lines of your original code).

```
Sub RemoveCarriageReturns()

Dim MyRange As Range
Dim ws As Worksheet

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

For Each ws In Worksheets
    With ws
        For Each MyRange In .UsedRange
            If 0 < InStr(MyRange, Chr(10)) Then
                MyRange = Replace(MyRange, Chr(10), "")
            End If
        Next MyRange
    End With
Next ws

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Public Function GetSheetNames(ByVal wbk As workbook) As String()
    Dim names() As String
    Dim count As Integer
    Dim i As Integer

        count = wbk.Worksheets.count

        ReDim names(count - 1)
        For i = 1 To wbk.Worksheets.count
            names(i - 1) = wbk.Worksheets(i).Name
        Next

        GetSheetNames = names

    End Function
```

Usage: `GetSheetNames(Application.ActiveWorkbook)`

UPDATE: For selected sheets only:

```
Public Function GetActiveSheetNames(ByVal wbk As workbook) As String()
Dim names() As String
Dim count As Integer
Dim i As Integer

    count = wbk.Windows(1).SelectedSheets.count

    ReDim names(count - 1)
    For i = 1 To wbk.Windows(1).SelectedSheets.count
        names(i - 1) = wbk.Windows(1).SelectedSheets(i).Name
    Next

    GetActiveSheetNames = names

End Function
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I've picked the other one as its a little simpler and I have to explain this to people who know even less about VBA than me.